# Regex Stripping HTML Tags

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I've got a coldfusion script which I've had hanging around for a while on my content management system. It's uses regex to strip out any crappy tags and characters out of the content.

I need to stop this script from stripping out any `<object>` and `<iframe>` tags.

I'm giving it a go but I think it's beyond my regex skills.

http://pastebin.com/rTtMyiQw

```
<cfparam name="Attributes.allowedclasses" default="">

<!--- turn allowed classes list to regular expression --->
<cfset Attributes.allowedclasses = Replace(Attributes.allowedclasses, ",", "|", "all")>

<cfset vBody="<body style='font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;'>">
<cfset vStart="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en' xml:lang='en'><head><title>Title</title></head>#vBody#">
<cfset vEnd="</body></html>">

<cfloop list="#Attributes.varnames#" index="theVariable">

    <cfset vIntVar=evaluate("caller.#theVariable#")>

    <cf_bocctrimformvars varnames="vIntVar" allowhtml="yes" quotes="unescape" allowPound="yes">

    <cfset vIntVarDebug=vIntVar>

    <!--- strip copy and paste word etc code formatting --->

    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "</?[a-z0-9-=""'!\$\?%&\*\+@~##;,\\]*:[a-z0-9 -=""'!\$\?%&\*\+@~##;,\\]*>", "", "all")>

    <!--- stop certain classes being stripped out --->
    <cfif ListLen(Attributes.allowedclasses) NEQ 0>
        <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, '<span class="(#Attributes.allowedclasses#)">([\s\S]*?)</span>', '<excludespan classexclude="\1">\2</excludespan>', 'all')>

        <!--- stop other classes being stripped out --->
        <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, '<([a-z0-9]+) class="(#Attributes.allowedclasses#)"[^>]*>', '<\1 classexclude="\2">', 'all')>
    </cfif>

    <!--- strip out span and font tags --->
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "</?(span|font)[^>]*>", "", "all")> 

    <!--- strip out rest of styles/classes --->
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "<([a-z0-9]+) (style|class)=[^>]*>", "<\1>", "all")>

    <!--- reset classes which shouldn't be stripped out --->
    <cfif ListLen(Attributes.allowedclasses) NEQ 0>
        <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, '<excludespan classexclude="([a-z0-9-]+)"[^>]*>', '<span class="\1">', 'all')>
        <cfset vIntVar=ReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, '</excludespan>', '</span>', 'all')>

        <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, '<([a-z0-9]+) classexclude="([a-z0-9-]+)"[^>]*>', '<\1 class="\2">', 'all')>
    </cfif>



    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "<\?xml[^>]*>", "", "all")>
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "<p>([[:space:]])*</p>", "", "all")>
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "</?U>", "", "all")>
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "</?DIV[^>]*>", "", "all")>
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "</?PRE>", "", "all")>
    <cfset vIntVar=ReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, 'target=""', '', 'all')>

    <!--- 
    DG 19/9/2004: fix put in to swap round <p> and <a> tags if a single <p> is inside an <a> 
    (which html tidy doesn't like 
    --->
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "<a([[:print:]]*)>[[:space:]]*<p>([[:print:]]*)</p>([[:space:]]*)</a>", "<p><a\1>\2</a></p>", 'all')>

    <cfset vIntVar=vStart & vIntVar & vEnd>

    <cflock name="tidy" type="exclusive" timeout="10">
        <cfscript>
        TidyObj = CreateObject("COM", "TidyCOM.TidyObject");
        TidyOptions = TidyObj.Options;
        TidyOptions.Doctype = "omit";
        TidyOptions.TidyMark = false;
        TidyOptions.OutputXml = false;
        TidyOptions.InputXml = false;
        TidyOptions.OutputXhtml = true;
        TidyOptions.ShowWarnings = false;
        TidyOptions.DropEmptyParas = true;
        TidyOptions.Quiet = true;
        TidyOptions.Indent = 0;
        TidyOptions.Wrap = 0;
        TidyOptions.QuoteAmpersand = true;

        vIntVar = TidyObj.TidyMemToMem(vIntVar);

        TidyObj = "";
        </cfscript>
    </cflock>


    <!--- strip any image tags inserted by drag and drop etc --->
    <cfset vIntVar=ReReplaceNoCase(vIntVar, "<img [^>]*>", "", "all")>


</cfloop>
```

Comment: I should warn you, asking parsing-html-with-regex questions tends to be a bit frowned on round here - see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I can understand it's not popular. This is an old script. Rather than rewrite it all I just need a quick fix for now.

Comment: Seriously? You need to at least do the work of identifying where in the code you've provided strips out the tags in question. Then someone might be inclined to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with orangepips, you should be asking a more specific question but I also like a challenge. I have tried parsing HTML on with REGEX before and can testify that it is not a good solution, especially when you are looking at a whole document and not just a simple string. However, sometimes you have to work with a tight space and you don't have a lot of options.

I looked through all of the REGEX expressions that you have here and ran them all against the following object tag. Not a single one of them detected the object tag which leads me to believe that the issue could be in TidyCOM. I poked around a bit looking for information about TidyCOM and the most current stuff I could find was from around 2001.

I understand that you are just looking to fix this script and move on but that might not be possible. You might start thinking about migrating this legacy stuff into a more current platform.

If you want to find out for sure where the issue is output the vIntVar variable to a text file after you concatenate the vStart, vIntVar and vEnd. Of course you could also just use the CF debugger but as I can recall that wasn't the easiest thing to get working.

Object tag I used to test expressions:

```
<object classid="clsid:F08DF954-8592-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628" id="Slider1" width="100" height="50">
  <param name="BorderStyle" value="1" />
  <param name="MousePointer" value="0" />
  <param name="Enabled" value="1" />
  <param name="Min" value="0" />
  <param name="Max" value="10" />
</object>
```

If you need some help understanding what the REGEX expressions are doing I have found [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to be a great tool. There are others but this is the one that I have used for years and it gets the job done.

Comment: Looks like I pasted the full code instead of my stripped down version. I spent most of Friday working on this and got it all working. I stripped out the TidyCOM and did the work with some custom regex which does the job fine. I'm sure for more complex manipulation there are other methods which are more suitable, but like you said sometimes you have to work in tight spaces. I think you've hit the nail on the head with this one Ryan, thanks for your help.